# What is a quicker method to differentiate $h(x)=2x-|3x-3|+|x^2-1|$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$h(x)=2x-|3x-3|+|x^2-1|$$

---

**My Approach:**

$$u=|3x-3|$$
$$u^2=(3x-3)^2$$
$$2 u'=2(3x-3)\cdot3$$

$$u'=3(3x-3)$$

$$m=|x^2-1|$$
$$m^2=(x^2-1)^2$$
$$2m'=2(x^2-1)\cdot 2x$$

$$m'=2x(x^2-1)$$

$$\therefore h'(x)=2-3(3x-3)+2x(x^2-1)$$

**Quicker and shorter method?**

Comment: Before we worry about quick, let us deal with right. The derivative of $u^2$ is $2uu'$. Now in fact the derivative of $|3x-3|$ does not exist at  $x=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how do we know that the derivative does not exist at $x=1$?

Comment: Actually we don't, the $ |x^2-1|$ could save us in principle, it has to be checked. But how do we know the derivative of $|3x-3|$ does not exist at $x=1$? The geometry, this is just a shifted version of the familiar $|x|$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh yeah, $|3x-3|$ has the end of the hat at $x=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was visually imagining $|x^2-1|$ graph, and it seems like there are two points that will have that end point. What I mean is there will be two points that will not be differentiable. Am I right? $x=1, x=-1$

Comment: Right @M.S.E. Because basically you don't want $x^2-1$ to be 0...$[|f(x)|]'=\frac{f(x) \cdot f'(x)}{|f(x)|}$ You don't want $f(x)$ to be 0.

Comment: Yes, $|x^2-1|$ near $\pm 1$ looks quite a bit like $|3x-3|$ does at $x=1$. But upside down at $x=-1$.  For the trouble at $x=-1$, note our function is $x^2-1$ for $x\lt -1$, derivative easy, it is $-(x^2-1)$ between $-1$ and $1$, derivative easy, it is $x^2-1$ for $x\gt 1$. The only points remaining at issue are $\pm 1$. It **could** be differentiable there, but in fact it isn't.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Funny that, when you are "thinking" that what you have done is enough and when finding a faster method, you start to realise its incomplete and actually it takes more work.

Comment: There are ways to speed up things, both the checking of differentiability/non-differentiability at the funny points, and the calculation at the nice points. A couple  of the answers point to such speedup. But first we needed to fix the things that were not right.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to note
is that,
if 
$f(x) = |g(x)|$,
then
$f(x) = -g(x)$ if $g(x) < 0$
(so $f'(x) = -g'(x)$),
and $f(x) = g(x)$ if $g(x) > 0$
(so $f'(x) = g'(x)$).
If $g(x) = 0$,
then $f(x)=0$,
but $f'(x)$ is not defined
unless $g'(x) = 0$,
in which case 
$f'(x) = 0$.

Therefore,
you have to look at 
all the different absolute values
in your function
and find when
each of them is positive,
negative, or zero.
One you have that,
you can determine
$h'(x)$
in all the intervals.

Comment: +1 , oh yes my answer is in fact wrong as random girl points out.

Comment: Yes. Squaring throws away the information about positive and negative.

Comment: Oh I see :/ hmmm

Comment: Annoying, isn't it? For each of $3x-3$ and $x^2-1$ you have to figure out where they are positive or negative.

Comment: Yep it is :////

Answer (score 2):

$u=|f(x)|$ squaring both sides gives $u^2=f^2(x)$ Differentiating both sides gives $2 u \cdot u'=2 f(x) \cdot f'(x)$ Now assuming $u \neq 0$ divide both sides by $2u$ giving us $u'=\frac{ f(x) \cdot f'(x)}{u}=\frac{f(x) \cdot f'(x)}{|f(x)|}$

Comment: And, of course, $f(x)/|f(x)|$ is just the sign of $f(x)$. However, this is not defined if $f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=|f(x)|=\sqrt{f^2(x)}$$
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}[f^2(x)]^{-\frac{1}{2}}.2f(x).f'(x)=\frac{f(x).f'(x)}{|f(x)|}$$